# Thread.CurrentPrincipal claims incorrectly to be anynomous

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, forms-authentication

I'm seeing requests on my server that appear to be made by an anynomous client, although I'm certain they were made by an authenticated user - I have fiddler logs showing that the client sent valid asp.net auth cookies, and server logs indicating that the cookie arrived and is valid.  The problem has been observed across all browsers.

The flow of data is:

1. User visits login url, on a machine that's part of a webfarm (all with the same machine, decrypt keys)
2. On successful forms authentication, user is redirect to a restricted url, their homepage
3. Homepage renders correctly, knowns the identify of the user, and includes javascript to perform 7 asynchronous post-backs to get additional data
4. Javascript kicks off 7 http.get requests, hitting different machines in the webfarm (assume round robin)
5. Server validates request: ~0.01% fail to authenticate.

Thoughts?

Now into details:

A very small number of the asynchronous requests land at my server (with evidence they were not manipulated or faked) and appear to be anonymous.  Of the 7 requests made, some number may or may not work (ie, 5/7 will succeed, 2 will fail).  There doesn't appear to be any patterns in success / failures. In the cases where my requests appear to be anonymous, the CurrentPrincipal.Identity records:

```
Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated; // false
Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name; // null (or empty, unsure off hand)
```

Dumping the http.context.request.params collection to a log file, I'm able to see the following relevent (and scrubbed) properties (complete params below):

```
context: {"userId":10000,"userName":"johnsmith"}
HTTP_COOKIE:.ASPXAUTH=[valid auth cookie value]
HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH:XMLHttpRequest
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
    AUTH_TYPE: 
    AUTH_USER: 
    AUTH_PASSWORD: 
    LOGON_USER: 
    REMOTE_USER: 
    HTTP_COOKIE: .ASPXAUTH=[valid auth cookie value]
```

I know the auth cookie is valid - during these same requests I'm able to decrypt the auth cookie and extract the following:

```
CookiePath: /
Expiration: 9/23/2105 8:14:22 PM
Expired: False
IsPersistent: True
IssueDate: 8/30/2010 2:54:22 PM
Name: johnsmith
UserData: 
Version: 2
```

Not sure how to proceed at this point.  This problem seems to have been exacerbated with our recent migration to mvc 2.0 / asp.net 4.0, but my confidence isn't high that was the cause.

I've reached out to a handful of my customers who have had this problem, and that's been even more frustrating (but does reflect what I'm able to read in my logs).  Once in this state, it's hard to get out of it.  Clearing cache and cookies seem to have no effect.  But, switching to a new browser and it's generally OK.  Likewise, waiting several hours and returning with the same browser and it's also generally ok, but not always.  As stated earlier, this is seen across all browsers.

Any suggestions?
Kevin

------------
Here is the remainder of the log snippet (scrubbed for pii) that I've captured:

```
8/30/2010 2:54:43 PM: Anonymous user detected:
    Identity Name:
    IsAuthenticated::False
HttpContextInformation to follow:

8/30/2010 2:54:43 PM: Request Param collection contents:
context: {"userId":10000,"userName":"johnsmith"}
    .ASPXAUTH: A3C6615642F1F543397160C84C0E016C8439BDF400B0130AADAB82C93E77FFF3BEAD7726223F02049FA65B2C3E1773928C0371C4F580F2432C1538551BC5654020AD76F37159BA6BB68D7A68744AE036
    ASP.NET_SessionId: m5vit3cyv0rsiosqg5xmhhuu
    ALL_HTTP: HTTP_CONNECTION:close
HTTP_ACCEPT:text/javascript, text/html, application/xml, text/xml, */*
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING:gzip, deflate
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE:en-us
HTTP_COOKIE:.ASPXAUTH=A3C6615642F1F543397160C84C0E016C8439BDF400B0130AADAB82C93E77FFF3BEAD7726223F02049FA65B2C3E1773928C0371C4F580F2432C1538551BC5654020AD76F37159BA6BB68D7A68744AE036
HTTP_HOST:www.host.com
HTTP_REFERER:http://www.host.com/
HTTP_USER_AGENT:Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.5 Mobile/8A293 Safari/6531.22.7
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR:166.137.139.139
HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH:XMLHttpRequest

    ALL_RAW: Connection: close
Accept: text/javascript, text/html, application/xml, text/xml, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-us
Cookie: .ASPXAUTH=A3C6615642F1F543397160C84C0E016C8439BDF400B0130AADAB82C93E77FFF3BEAD7726223F02049FA65B2C3E1773928C0371C4F580F2432C1538551BC5654020AD76F37159BA6BB68D7A68744AE036
Host: www.host.com
Referer: http://www.host.com/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.5 Mobile/8A293 Safari/6531.22.7
X-Forwarded-For: 166.137.139.139
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest

    APPL_MD_PATH: /LM/W3SVC/792523/Root
    APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH: d:\localpath\
    AUTH_TYPE: 
    AUTH_USER: 
    AUTH_PASSWORD: 
    LOGON_USER: 
    REMOTE_USER: 
    CERT_COOKIE: 
    CERT_FLAGS: 
    CERT_ISSUER: 
    CERT_KEYSIZE: 
    CERT_SECRETKEYSIZE: 
    CERT_SERIALNUMBER: 
    CERT_SERVER_ISSUER: 
    CERT_SERVER_SUBJECT: 
    CERT_SUBJECT: 
    CONTENT_LENGTH: 0
    CONTENT_TYPE: 
    GATEWAY_INTERFACE: CGI/1.1
    HTTPS: off
    HTTPS_KEYSIZE: 
    HTTPS_SECRETKEYSIZE: 
    HTTPS_SERVER_ISSUER: 
    HTTPS_SERVER_SUBJECT: 
    INSTANCE_ID: 792523
    INSTANCE_META_PATH: /LM/W3SVC/792523
    LOCAL_ADDR: 10.248.50.207
    PATH_INFO: /resource
    PATH_TRANSLATED: d:\localpath\resource
    QUERY_STRING: context={%22userId%22:10000,%22userName%22:%22johnsmith%22}
    REMOTE_ADDR: 10.208.205.171
    REMOTE_HOST: 10.208.205.171
    REMOTE_PORT: 37966
    REQUEST_METHOD: GET
    SCRIPT_NAME: /resouce
    SERVER_NAME: www.host.com
    SERVER_PORT: 80
    SERVER_PORT_SECURE: 0
    SERVER_PROTOCOL: HTTP/1.0
    SERVER_SOFTWARE: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
    URL: /resource
    HTTP_CONNECTION: close
    HTTP_ACCEPT: text/javascript, text/html, application/xml, text/xml, */*
    HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING: gzip, deflate
    HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE: en-us
    HTTP_COOKIE: .ASPXAUTH=A3C6615642F1F543397160C84C0E016C8439BDF400B0130AADAB82C93E77FFF3BEAD7726223F02049FA65B2C3E1773928C0371C4F580F2432C1538551BC5654020AD76F37159BA6BB68D7A68744AE036
    HTTP_HOST: www.host.com
    HTTP_REFERER: http://www.host.com/
    HTTP_USER_AGENT: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.5 Mobile/8A293 Safari/6531.22.7
    HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR: 166.137.139.139
    HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH: XMLHttpRequest


8/30/2010 2:54:43 PM: Auth Ticket collection contents:
    CookiePath: /
    Expiration: 9/23/2105 8:14:22 PM
    Expired: False
    IsPersistent: True
    IssueDate: 8/30/2010 2:54:22 PM
    Name: johnsmith
    UserData: 
    Version: 2
```

Comment: +1 For thorough research prior to asking :) but OMG wall of text O.o

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, it sounds like this would be perfect for using up a Microsoft support incident. If you have an MSDN subscription, you probably have a few free incident resolutions per year.

Comment: +1 For such thorough information. I agree with Stephen that this is a good incident for which to contact Microsoft Support. The only thing that comes to mind: Is there any thread manipulation being done by the application, i.e. are any threads being spawned outside of the ones automatically managed by the ASP.Net thread pool?

Comment: @eglasius: Just a shot in the dark. We're talking about a web farm. Have you checked the time settings on the servers? Are both timezone and the actual time the same?

Comment: @GrimaceofDespair missed your comment before, yes it was a web farm, but my problem was a very silly one / see the answer I had posted back then

Comment: Ok, I only notice now there was another answer from you. I think I recognize that moment when you solve a though problem which leaves you with an abiguous feeling: not sure whether you need to be euforic for having it solved, or ashamed to pieces for having had your head up your *rse for so long :P

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This answer works, but is disappointing and alarming at the same time.

I spent 2 months working part time with MSDN technical support, and we finally found a work-around for this problem.  I'm going to leave it to Microsoft to fix the problem, as it’s almost certainly an issue in the .net framework.  But first, let me summarize the problem, give additional relevant background information and a few interesting things we found along the way.

The symptom was fleeting: Our website had a few reports of users who would authenticate with our website and see the correct state.  But seemingly randomly, they’d be signed out of our website, or occasionally, experience the anonymous view.  It was very frustrating, an nearly impossible to reproduce locally, in house.

Also on symptoms:  through logging we saw mobile (iphone, ipad & android) browsers were disproportionately impacted, although all browsers and operating systems were impacted to some degree.  And one last random symptom: It’d work for a user one day, not the next, and later in the afternoon, work again.  Of course, switching browsers almost always fixed the problem.

We quickly assumed an auth issue, likely around the authentication cookie.  The strange part was, I was able to prove (tracing) that the requests that were erroring included a proper cookie that I was able to decrypt, but that the .net framework was ignoring, in a non-deterministic way.  I eventually began logging all requests that were in this state – auth cookie ignored by the .net framework, but seemingly valid to me, and found around 2% of my users were impacted.

I switched from using Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity to HttpContext.Current.User.Identity, to no avail, and tried a handful of other settings.  Curiously, the only change I was able to make that made a dent was migrate to the .net 4 framework (from 3.5).  The problem became an order of magnitude worst.  Also tried various load balancer configurations, and was able to rule out multiple machine configurations – the same machine that issued the auth cookie would later reject it.

To re-iterate the symptoms: we had certain users (non-deterministic) who at times would not be able to user our website in an authenticated mode (also non-deterministic). Cute.

By now, the product team in Redmond was involved, and also stumped.  But they did come up with a suggestion, which ultimately resolved the issue, here goes:
Try forcing the Microsoft.net framework to use cookies as the authentication mode, as opposed to using a cookieless state:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms cookieless="UseCookies" />
</authentication>
```

Flipped the switch and instantly the problematic requests ended (once I expired the session of those in an odd state).

While I’m glad that the problem was resolved – or rather worked around, it’s the non-deterministic handling of various browsers that worries me.  Why would the .net framework see a browser one day, and treat it as supporting cookies, and later the same day say it should use a cookieless session?

My last concern is around how many other sites out there are losing 2% of their authenticated traffic without knowing?  Considering the fix, it feels very much like a bug in the .net 4 framework.

Comment: Sounds like you need to set the machine key in web.config.  FormsAuthentication cookies are encrypted and decrypted using the machinekey.  Therefore in a webfarm environment you need to manually set the machine key the same for all nodes in the farm.  Otherwise only the server that issued the ticket can decrypt it.

Comment: @reach4thelasers it's definitely not that, when you change the machine key then you can't Decrypt in that same request. I'm investigating a similar problem, same situation, but with UseCookies! :~

Answer (score 2):

Don't use this in ASP.NET authentication:

`Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;`

Instead stick to:

```
HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
```

For info see this article [link text](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SystemThreadingThreadCurrentPrincipalVsSystemWebHttpContextCurrentUserOrWhyFormsAuthenticationCanBeSubtle.aspx) but more importantly the comments including the first and last ones - the article is old 2004 but the arguments are still valid today.

Therefore, instead of:

`Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated; // false
Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name; // null (or empty, unsure off hand)`

You should use:

```
 HttpContext.Current.User.Identity...
```

In which case you can also use AuthenticateRequest instead of PostAuthenticateRequest because there is no Thread issue to workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you begin by checking that the incoming web request actually has an authentication cookie and that it is valid. The forms authentication module takes the incoming web request and looks to see if it has a authentication cookie. If so then it attempts to decode it and then generate the principle using its contained value. As your principle is empty it means that either there was no authentication cookie provided in the request or there was an error decoding or it was decoded and found to be expired or it was decoded and oddly it has empty string as the username.

I recommend you create your own module that is called before the others and you check for yourself if the cookie is present and then if present decode it to see what it contains. That would give you more detail on what it happening. Your own module to reuse methods from the FormsAuthentication module to perform these actions. Such as....

```
ForsmAuthentication.Decrypt(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the authentication I use with most of my ASP.NET / Mvc applications that needs basic authentication. I believe it would help and would allow you to store additional data in the AuthenticationCookie. If you use this before .Net does their authentication .Net will override your setting of the current principal and user properties, using the PostAuthenticateRequest will fix the overriding issue. Let me know if you have any questions.

```
// Code that goes in the Global.asax.cs
// that runs after .Net has done it's authentication
protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IPrincipal user = HttpContext.Current.User;

    if (user == null) { return; }

    FormsIdentity formsIdentity = user.Identity as FormsIdentity;

    if (formsIdentity == null || !formsIdentity.IsAuthenticated) { return; }

    Principal principal = new Principal(new Identity(formsIdentity.Ticket));
    HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
}
```

```
// Base implementation of the System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal interface.
public class Principal : System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal
{
    #region Fields

    private IIdentity _identity = null;

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    public Principal(IIdentity identity)
    {
        _identity = identity;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public IIdentity Identity
    {
        get
        {
            return _identity;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    public bool IsInRole(string role)
    {
        return (_identity != null && _identity.IsAuthenticated);
    }

    #endregion
}



// Base implementation of the System.Security.Principal.IIdentity interface. 
public class Identity : System.Security.Principal.IIdentity
{
    #region Fields

    private readonly int _userId;
    private readonly bool _isAuthenticated;
    private readonly string _userName;

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    public Identity(FormsAuthenticationTicket formsAuthTicket)
    {
        if (formsAuthTicket == null)
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException("FormsAuthenticationTicket may not be null.");
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(formsAuthTicket.UserData))
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException("FormsAuthenticationTicket.UserData may not be null or empty.");
        }

        string[] userData = formsAuthTicket.UserData.Split(new[] {"|"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        if (userData.Length < 1)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("formsAuthTicket", userData, "UserData does not contain a UserId and or a SiteId");
        }

        _userId = Convert.ToInt32(userData[0]);
        _isAuthenticated = !formsAuthTicket.Expired;
        _userName = formsAuthTicket.Name;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public int UserId
    {
        get
        {
            return _userId;
        }
    }
    public string AuthenticationType
    {
        get
        {
            return "Forms";
        }
    }
    public bool IsAuthenticated
    {
        get
        {
            return _isAuthenticated;
        }
    }
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _userName;
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

I Hope this helps to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

re bounty:

> I'm seeing this in an Azure application with asp.net 4.0, cookie is there and you can decrypt it with FormsAuthentication.Decrypt and read everything (not expired, correct value, etc, etc); just like the OP described. Unlike the OP scenario, I was already using UseCookies, and still get the same. Bounty is for the specific reason within asp.net that can trigger this problem and solution.

My case was such a silly issue:

1. Issue tokens via `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie` and a corresponding redirect
2. Configure the `<forms>` tag in the web.config
3. Check `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` in the page / is false
4. The cookie is there and you can even decrypt it via `FormsAuthentication.Decrypt`

problem: don't forget to set `<authentication mode="Forms">`, lol, total fail ...

My 2 cents on the OP: some internal links/redirects/js can break havoc when *trying* to use cookieless authorization. Additionally cookie support detection is not very precise.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, based on my past experience, that this issue is in fact caused by ASP.NET not recognizing IE10+.  Not known the browser and its capabilities, it falls back to cookieless authentication (a bad or at least outdated assumption).

Updates for the browser definition files were released available here.   The problem is not present with .NET 4.5

https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600088

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600100

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2608565